# Change Solaris 10 password with script

Tags: unix, solaris

Can somebody help me to create a script that changes my password for a Solaris based server? I am not the root user. Usually I change my password like this: I type in the terminal "passwd" then it asks me to enter login password, I insert it, then it ask for the new password, I insert it, then it asks to re-enter new password, I insert it. Does anybody knows how to do this via script? Or even better how to change the password by a command written in only one line?
   I want to create a java app that connects to the server and changes the password.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is deliberately almost impossible to accomplish - because it's a very, very bad, insecure idea to script passwords.  Doing so almost certainly compromises the password and therefore the account and everything it has access to.

The Solaris `passwd` utility uses `getpassphrase()` to read passwords directly from the controlling terminal - the keyboard.  You can find [the source code here](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/lib/libc/port/stdio/getpass.c#62).

From [the `getpassphrase()` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1465/getpassphrase-3c.html#scrolltoc):

> **Description**
>
> The `getpass()` function **opens the process's controlling terminal**,
>   writes to that device the null-terminated string *prompt*, disables
>   echoing, reads a string of characters up to the next newline character
>   or EOF, restores the terminal state and closes the terminal.
>
> The `getpassphrase()` function is identical to `getpass()`, except
>   that it reads and returns a string of up to 257 characters in length.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Henle. I understand that this method is insecure but I don't want to use it for other users. I want to use it for me. Once in a month I have to connect to 5 different servers because the password expires and change the password manually. I wanted to create and app that connects to servers and changes my password more faster.